# How to fix incorrect folding of Ruby for Geany

Tags: ruby, folding, geany, code-folding

Some Ruby code won't fold correctly in Geany.

For example, if I have

```
def validate(arr)
  if arr.any?(&:empty?)
    fail
  end
end

validate(["a", "b", "c"])
validate([""])
```

then folding the `if` folds too much:

[image: First screenshot]
[image: Second screenshot]

Whereas if I use quotation marks around the text and question mark of the Ruby symbol (that is, change `:empty?` into `:"empty?"`, then it folds correctly:

[image: Third screenshot]
[image: Fourth screenshot]

How can I make Geany fold the code correctly, without having to change `:empty?` into `:"empty?"`? Is this a configuration thing, or a bug?

Comment: Isn't it clearly a bug?

Comment: it looks like geany miss-interprets the `?` at the end of `:empty?` as not being part of the symbol (it also gives it a different color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current consensus, based on the comments, is that it's just a bug in Geany.

I've created a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/geany/+bug/1337015